# Cannot show a variable value on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a dynamic html using jquery.

I have a checkbox for the desired language for the labels of a form but when I apply the parseHTML() those variables do not display any info.

Here's the code.

```
$desiredLanguageCompany = "";

$labelCompanyUK = "Company name ";
$labelCompanyGerman = "Unternehmen ";
$labelCompanyFrench = "Nom de la soci&eacute;t&eacute; ";
$labelCompanyItalian = "Societ&agrave; ";
$labelCompanyDanish = "Virksomhedsnavn ";
$labelCompanySwedish = "Not Provided ";
$labelCompanyFinish = "Yritys ";
$labelCompanyNorwegian = "Selskap ";

$formGroupCompany = '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label for="inputLastname" class="control-label">' + $desiredLanguageCompany +
    '<span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" aria-required="true" required="" placeholder=""' +
    'id="inputLastname" class="form-control input-lg" name="last_name" /></div>';
```

and here are the functions:

```
$("#checkUK").change(function () {
    $desiredLanguageCompany = $labelCompanyUK;
    console.log($desiredLanguageCompany);
});

$("#testButton").click(function () {
    $jqueryObject = $($.parseHTML($personalizedHTML));
    $('#test').append($jqueryObject);
    $('form').append($formGroupCompany);
    $('#resultTextArea').val('<!DOCTYPE html>' + $('#test').html() + '</html>');
});
```

So basically when you check the language option the variable must be set and it's doing it but when I apply the parseHTML no info for that variable is displaying.

Should I do something different? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the console tells ? (ctrl + maj + j under firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$formGroupCompany` is built `$desiredLanguageCompany` is empty.

An alternative would be to to call a function that returns the html:

```
function getGroupCompany() {
 return '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label for="inputLastname" class="control-label">' + $desiredLanguageCompany +
        '<span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" aria-required="true" required="" placeholder=""' +
        'id="inputLastname" class="form-control input-lg" name="last_name" /></div>';
}
```

And

```
$('form').append(getGroupCompany());
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.